# How to count the number of visitors seeing the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need a way of determining how many users are looking at a particular page at the current moment.

For a live example of what I want, [see this link](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?city=-73635&ssne=Singapore&ssne_untouched=Singapore&error_url=http://www.booking.com/hotel/sg/mandarin.en-gb.html?sid=133d854a051e93d98828b57c02918058;dcid=1;dva=0;&highlighted_hotels=25028&dcid=1&sid=133d854a051e93d98828b57c02918058&si=ai,co,ci,re,di&ss=Singapore&checkin_monthday=0&checkin_year_month=0&checkout_monthday=0&checkout_year_month=0&idf=on).

Under some of the hotel listings, you will see:

> There are [Number] people looking at this hotel.

Can anyone tell me how this is done? I am using MVC3 and C#.

Comment: @emre: please don't use URL shorteners to improve the appearance of long links; instead, use the technique illustrated by [ThinkingStiff's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9713034/revisions).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the Application State to store those number, you can identify them with a unique session ID or your UserID:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf9xhdz4(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a number of different ways, if it was me I'd store pageviews somehow (database, flatfile, static variable, application state, whatever floats your boat really) with a DateTime and decide on a length of time to include in the count, e.g. any pageviews in the last minute or whatever you like.

If you wanted to get more accurate you could also do some kind of AJAX polling to check if people are still on the page.